# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\right)^3 dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I’m looking for a closed form of this integral $$I_3=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\right)^3 dx$$ I’ve managed to evaluate $$I_1=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx=\pi \ln 2$$ with the change of variable $x =\tan \theta $, $dx=(1+(\tan \theta)^2) d\theta $ giving $$I_1=-2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln(\cos \theta ) d\theta$$ which is classic. But I’m stuck with the power $(\ln (\cos \theta))^3$ in $I_3$. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

> $$\int_0^{+\infty}\!\left(\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\right)^3\!{\rm d}x=\frac{9\pi}{4}  \zeta(3)+\frac{3 \pi}{2} \ln^3 2-\frac{21\pi}{8}\ln^2 2-\frac{33\pi}{16} \ln 2-\frac{7 \pi ^3}{32}-\frac{57 \pi }{64}.$$

*Proof.* Observe that
$$
\left(\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\right)^3=-\partial_s^3 \left.\left(\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^s}\right)\right|_{s=3} \tag1
$$
Then you may write
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^s}{\rm d}x
&=\frac12\int_0^1u^s\left(\frac1u-1\right)^{-1/2}\frac{{\rm d}u}{u^2},\quad \color{purple}{u=\frac{1}{1+x^2},\, x=\left(\frac1u-1\right)^{1/2}}\\\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1u^{s-3/2}\left(1-u\right)^{-1/2}{\rm d}u\\\\
&=\frac12\frac{\Gamma\left(s-\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(s)}\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(s-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(s)} \qquad \qquad (2)
\end{align}
$$ where, in the last step, we have used the classic *[Euler beta function integral representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).*

Now, performing $\displaystyle -\partial_s^3 $ to $(2)$ and using $(1)$, you easily get a closed form expression for your integral with the help of Wolfram|Alpha for the computation of
$$
-\partial_s^3 \left.\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(s-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(s)}\right)\right|_{s=3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $ I_{m,n}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln^m(1+x^2)}{(1+x^2)^n}dx
$ and apply the corresponding reduction formula
$$I_{m,n} =\frac m{n-1} I_{m-1,n}-\frac m{n-1} I_{m-1,n-1}
+\frac{n-\frac32}{n-1} I_{m,n-1}
$$
recursively to express the original integral
$I_{3,3}=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\right)^3 dx $ as

\begin{align}
I_{3,3}
= \frac34 I_{0,3}+ \frac{21}8 I_{0,2}- \frac{27}8 I_{0,1}+  \frac{3}8 I_{3,1}-\frac{21}{16}I_{2,1}-\frac{33}{16} I_{1,1}
\end{align}
The six reduced integrals are known and given below
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\frac\pi2, \>\>\>
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\frac\pi4,\>\>\>
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3}dx=\frac{3\pi}{16},\\ &\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln\frac{1+x^2}4}{1+x^2}dx=0,\>\>
 \int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln^2\frac{1+x^2}4}{1+x^2}dx=\pi\zeta(2),\>\>
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln^3\frac{1+x^2}4}{1+x^2}dx=6\pi\zeta(3)
\end{align}
As a result

$$\frac{I_{3,3}}\pi=\frac{9}{4}  \zeta(3)+(\frac94\ln2-\frac{21}{16}) \zeta(2) +\frac{3}{2} \ln^3 2-\frac{21}{8}\ln^2 2-\frac{33}{16} \ln 2 -\frac{57}{64}
$$

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
$$
I_3 =\lim_{\beta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial^3}{\partial \beta^3}\int \left(1+x^2\right)^{\beta-3}dx
$$

Comment: How do I evaluate your integral? Thanx.